# Documentation on arguments and return values of arbitrary PowerQuery functions

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Lets take https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-splitcolumn as an example. This function takes `splitter as function` as it's third argument. Now how do I know what arguments and/or return values this `splitter` has (ie. what's the signature of the splitter function)? Where can I check that?

Surely I can navigate here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/splitter-functions and take any function from there as an example but unfortunately those functions return *the actual splitter* function, which again is ambiguous.

I'm asking as I would like to either create my own splitter or be able to use that splitter in my own logic; thus I need to know what arguments I am to expect to be passed to a splitter function.

Comment: What about the [MS  Documentation for the Splitter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/splitter-splittextbydelimiter)

Comment: That page also says that it returns a function and explains briefly what this function *does* but not what's the functions *signature*

Comment: You don't know if the docs don't tell you. `splitter as function` is the actual signature, and it means you can pass any function to `Table.SplitColumn`. If it's not the right type at runtime to be applied, you'll get an error. It's not possible in M to be more specific than `function` for an argument type -- although the language has specific function types, parameter declarations only allow primitive types (of which `function` is one). So you'll have to infer, or determine by experiment, that the function required in this case takes one parameter and returns a list.

Comment: Note that it *is* possible to get the type of a function by simply evaluating it as an expression (e.g. `= Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",")`) but this often still won't tell you anything about the actual types required or expected, just their number (`Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter` returns a `function(line as any) as any`), so not much help there. Unfortunately these dynamic functions are the norm for M built-ins.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that try-and-error approach, to figure out that in fact it takes 1 argument (ie. a string) and returns a list is *some* way of approaching it, although not really something one would like to struggle with. The docs wouldn't necessarily have to define generic `function` as something of a more concrete type but at least give you list of arguments that `SplitColumn` is going to pass to the callback function you must provide as well as a return value (if needed, which in fact is needed here). But well... tough luck:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with `#shared`? Maybe it might help you.

Try these two queries out:

```
let
    Source = #shared,
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "Table.SplitColumn")),
    Value = #"Filtered Rows"{0}[Value]
in
    Value
```

Which gives you:
[image]

```
let
    Source = #shared,
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter")),
    Value = #"Filtered Rows"{0}[Value]
in
    Value
```

Which gives you:
[image]